OpenLayers: feature.set() -> feature.changed() doesn't seem to change data
I want my features to change every time I hit checkbox. I've added event listenter to a change. I supposed I would go this statement (as I stated that the 'zero' value is [0]) if (currentValue.length == 1) { feature.set('number', data_languages[language][index]); feature.changed() }
Then it was supposed to go 'else' statement (as any data in my variable data_languages[language][index] is an array of 4 elements). But I keep going the 'if' statement.
input.addEventListener('change', function () {
        console.log(vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures())
        if (input.checked) {
            var language = Object.keys(language_codes).find(key => language_codes[key] == input.id.split(':')[0]);
            var category = input.id.split(':')[1]
            if (category) {
                category = parseInt(category)
                // console.log(language, category)
                var features = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
                features.forEach(function (feature, index) {
                    var currentValue = feature.get('number');
                    if (currentValue.length == 1) {
                        feature.set('number', data_languages[language][index]);
                        feature.changed()
                    } else {
                        console.log(feature.get('number'))
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });


Is the number preset to an array?  If not currentValue.length might throw an error.

@Mike Yes, it's preset var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource, style: function (feature) { feature.set('number', [0]); ...

The reason why you're not getting the expected result is because you're setting number in your style function to [0]. This happens every time the style function is called, which is almost every render frame (i.e. whenever the map is animated or interacted with). So your features will constantly be reset to their initial number value.
To solve this issue,do not initialize the number value in your features in the style function, but in a source addfeature listener:
verctorSource.on('addfeature', (e) => e.feature.set('number', [0]));

Also note that you don't need to call feature.changed() after feature.set(...), because set(...) triggers a change already.

What if I want my styles to update on a change of a feature? Currently, I face an issue when my map updates once the first change was made, the following changes are displayed only when I move the map
UPD: I made a test: unlike you recommended, I placed feature.changed() and it worked: the styles update on every feature change

When the old and new object are equal, set() will not trigger a change. This is likely the case in your setting. I guess you're calling set() with a reference to the same array.
